# Why won't the if statement detect my game state

Tags: java, plugins, enums, listeners

I am new to Java and I have come across a "bug" in my code that I am having trouble understanding/fixing.  To give you some background knowledge,  I set up an Enum that states all the game states (below)

```
public enum GameState {

    IN_LOBBY(true), IN_GAME(false), POST_GAME(false), RESETTING(false);

    private boolean canJoin;    
    private static GameState currentState;

    GameState(boolean canJoin) {
        this.canJoin = canJoin;
    }

    public boolean canJoin() {
        return canJoin();
    }

    public static void setState(GameState state) {
        GameState currentState = state;
    }

    public static boolean isState(GameState state) {
        return GameState.currentState == state;
    }

    public static GameState getState() {
        return currentState;
    }
}
```

In my `main.java` class I specify in the `onEnable` method to set the GameState to `IN_LOBBY`.

Basically what I am trying to do is in a BlockBreakEvent Listener I want to say is

```
if (GameState.isState(GameState.IN_LOBBY)) {
    Location bLoc = block.getLocation();
    ChatUtilties.errorPlayer("You may not break blocks at this time.", player);
    bLoc.getBlock().setType(Material.type);
}
```

In other words I am trying to detect if the GameState is `IN_LOBBY` and if so make it so that players can not break blocks.  But currently two problems have arisen.

1. For some reason when the GameState is `IN_LOBBY` the plugin won't even take notice.  It just ignores that if statement. It won't even send the message, as if the gamestate was not `IN_LOBBY`.
2. I'm not sure how to dynamically change the material based on what block the player broke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your setter is wrong:

```
public static void setState(GameState state) {
    GameState currentState = state;
}
```

You are creating a new local variable currentState here, instead of using the existing field. This happens because you wrote the variable type in front of it, creating a new initialization statement.

Instead use:

```
public static void setState(GameState state) {
    currentState = state;
}
```

(Since currentState is a static field `GameState.currentState = state;` would also work in this case)

**Edit:**

Another problem is with your canJoin method.

```
public boolean canJoin() {
    return canJoin();
}
```

this method calls itself recursivly without any end condition. So you will get a StackOverflowException if you ever try to call it.

Instead you probably meant to return the canJoin field:

```
public boolean canJoin() {
    return canJoin;
}
```

Comment: also mention the same thing for his isState method, he should use return currentState == state

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz: His currentState field is static. So refering to it by `GameState.currentState` should cause no problems. Of course the question wether it is good desgin to have the current state saved in a static field is another question, but i feel adressing this would go beyond this questions scope.

Comment: Thank you!  Do you by any chance know how to make it so that when the player breaks a block it replaces it back?  Obviously, I am doing it wrong.

Comment: I guess this is some Minecraft related stuff (Block Breaking). Sry, but i really don't know enough about programming for Minecraft to help you with this specific problem.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERSActually I found a solution to that!  apparently doing `event.setCancelled(true);` will do the trick!